# How to manually create a class instance with Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am using Spring Framework for Dependency Injection. At one point I inject an instance of a certain class into another class and I need to create an additional temporary object of the same class. I probably could change the scope of the injected bean to prototype but I wonder if there's another simple way to do that?

My only idea is to create it using `new` but wanted to know if there is a proper way to do it with Spring.

Just a general example:

```
@Inject
private ClassA classA;

public void methodA() {

// here I need another instance of ClassA to be used in the scope of this method

}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this "temporary" class? Do you need a prototype bean instead?

Comment: @chrylis I use Spring for my automated testing framework so it's probably not the classic Spring usage. In my case this object represents some logical element in the application I am testing and here I need to encapsulate an additional element that only relevant within this method. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Prototype scope and `ApplicationContext` are all you need

Comment: If you want the temporary object to be managed by Spring, you have to instantiate it using Spring.  If you don't want it to be managed by Spring, use `new`.  Not all objects in your program `have` to be managed by Spring. There are so-called `domain` objects that you can manage yourself.

Comment: It sounds like what you ought to do is switch to constructor injection instead of field injection, which would let you very easily provide a mock service or sample configuration data as constructor arguments.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks, that sounds interesting. Could please point me to some examples?

Comment: See http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/. Note that as of Spring 4.3, you don't need any injection annotations at all if the class only has a single constructor.

Comment: you can make use of BeanUtils like BeanUtils.instantiate(Class<T> clazz) or simply  classA.getClass().newInstance()

Answer (score 4):

Just subclass it and use `prototype` scope.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

public void methodA(){
  // will return a new instance (still a bean) every time its called
  ClassB bean = context.getBean(ClassB.class); 
  ...
}
```

You can also cast down to `ClassA` and use bean name if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It is an interesting approach. According to what I know however, using `getBean` directly is considered a bad practice.

Comment: `getBean` is a perfectly common method to get tighter scope beans (such as request, prototype) inside broader scope beans (such as singleton). If you don't want to use it, then the only option is to use [scoped beans as dependencies](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) which requires aop proxies in place, which is impractical and error prone (especially with prototype scope). Remember, you should **not use** `new` keyword while creating beans with injected (autowired) fields.

Comment: Not very nice approach. It makes your class depending from the whole applicationContext. Bad design and hard to test because you should mock whole context. It is much better to use Factory-bean in this case.

Answer (score -5):

There are two ways you can do this based on the purpose of another instance of ClassA.
First, 
you can create a new object using "new" keyword.

```
public void methodA()
{
 ClassA antherClassAInstance = new ClassA();   
}
```

This approch is suitable when you want to use the new instance only for this method.

Second,
Declare global instance using @Autowired annotation.

```
@Autowired
ClassA antherClassAInstance;
```

Comment: @Autowired will provide the same functionality is @Inject that I am curretly using. It will wire the singleton. I also mentioned that using `new` is my second option but wanted to know if there are alternatives.

Comment: can you tell me the purpose of the new instance? You can clone the first instance if you want to.